# Spring Integration & Kafka Consumer: Stop message-driven-channel-adapter right after records are sucessfully fetched

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-xd, spring-kafka

I'm using the following confing:

- spring-integration-kafka 2.1.0.RELEASE
- kafka-clients 0.10.0.1
- Kafka 0.10.x.x
- spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE

I created my custom Kafka-source module for SpringXD. I set my consumer logic and my `message-driven-channel-adapter` (which I'm using in conjunction with a `control-bus` to stop my channel adapter). So far so good. Also I'm using as a kafka property `max.poll.record=10` to fetch 10 records per poll.

I would like to make sure that I'm stopping my channel right after all records (in this case 10 records) have been successfully fetched.

So for example: I would like to **AVOID** Stopping reading when not all records are been successfully fetched and processed (that is, when the records are not been sent to the output channel).

Is there a way to tell that?

This is my xml config, just in case:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<int:channel id="input_to_control_bus" />
<int:channel id="output" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.kafka.source.logic" />


<int:control-bus id="my_control_bus" input-channel="input_to_control_bus" />

<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="kafkaInboundChannelAdapterTesting" listener-container="container1"
    auto-startup="false" phase="100" send-timeout="5000" channel="output"
    mode="record" message-converter="messageConverter" />

<bean id="messageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter" />

<!--Consumer -->
<bean id="container1"
    class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
                    <entry key="enable.auto.commit" value="false" />
                    <entry key="auto.commit.interval.ms" value="100" />
                    <entry key="session.timeout.ms" value="15000" />
                    <entry key="max.poll.records" value="3" />
                    <entry key="group.id" value="bridge-stream-testing" />
                    <entry key="key.deserializer"
                        value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer" />
                    <entry key="value.deserializer"
                        value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer" />
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>

    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties">
            <constructor-arg name="topics" value="testing-topic" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

**[UPDATE N°1]**
Why do I want to do this?
These are the details:

- I would like to read at most **X** messages every **Y** minutes from a Kafka topic.
- I use `max.poll.records` to ensure that I'm fetching at most **X** messages per poll.
- One scenario that I would like to handle is: what happens if in one specific polling of messages, I poll less messages than **X**. That implies that I should stop the channel without waiting for **X** messages, otherwise I would have to wait until a future poll of messages to reach those **X** messages.

Those are some details about this scenario. There are more scenarios but I don't want to mix it using the same SO question.

**[UPDATE N°2]**

Some thoughts after Artem's answer.

- What happens if I don't define a `max.poll.records` and just wait until having reached **Y** minutes and having counted **X** messages, and then `stop` the channel?
- Do some messages would be lost because could not be read, or those message that couldn't be read will be read when I `start` again the channel?

I want to avoid to keep messages in memory, that is the reason I was using `message-driven-channel-adapter` + `max.poll.records`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can suggest is like `AtomicInteger` bean, which is increased on each processed record and when you are reaching the threshold you perform the `stop()` for your `kafkaInboundChannelAdapterTesting`.

Comment: In that case, how can I control the record that I'm processing? I mean, how can I tell that I'm processing one specific record? In that scenario you mentioned, the only thing that I care is to tell that one record is coming through (just the notification) but how to tell?

Comment: No, I mean that you can use `WireTap` for the internal channel and increment that counter in its own flow. The message will be send to the process as is. Just add `<wire-tap channel="messageCounterChannel" pattern="output"/>`

Comment: I see a new issue. Let's say `max.poll.records = 10`. So I'm expecting to count 10 messages then stop the channel. But for some reason, there are less than 10 messages within the Kafka topic (let's say 4 messages). Then, when I'm using the `wire-tap` + `AtomicInteger` how to tell if I'm the messages that I'm counting belong to the current polling?

Comment: Well, it's absolutely different story. Your original request was like "do not stop until I have 10 messages". There was no requests about single poll. Maybe we can help you better if you share the business requirements. I fully can't imagine the case why I would like to stop polling Kafka for messages. That part in your question confuses me a bit. Maybe you need to take a look into `aggregator` pattern?

Comment: I did 2 updates to the description. Please check and let me know if that is enough.

Comment: What about the comment in my **[Update N°2]**? I just reupdated it.

Comment: Well, looks like you should study Kafka more. Actually you don't lose messages there at all. And if you use `Manual` (or batch) commit, nothing will be checkpointed in the offset commit. You don't need to worry about that - just stream messages from the Kafka and that's all!

Comment: I'm not saying that I'm loosing messages from the kafka topic. I know pretty well the messages will be there in the topic. What I'm saying is this scenario (from spring perspective): let's say I'm going to stop my channel if I count 100 messages. `max.poll.records` is 100 as well. First poll I got 50 messages. Second poll I got 80 messages (so during the 2nd poll I reach count  = 100). What is gonna happen with the remaining 30 messages that I haven't read yet. Will those messages read during the next poll (by my spring logic)??

Comment: If you are not ack them, then yes, they will be read one more time the next poll. That is the point of that `offset` management - to be able to read from some checkpoint again.

Comment: Then I would be good. Whatever happens, If I stop reading **whenever I want**, next time I will start reading where it left off.

Comment: Something like that. Just be sure to choose the proper ack mode: http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#committing-offsets

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Btw, I guess a suitable way to use `wire-tap` in this scenario would be to use the `wire-tap` + `service-activator`. So the 'wire-tap' sends a message to a xxx channel, and the `service-activator` will be listening the `xxx` channel. The `AtomicInteger` bean will be referenced in the `service-activator`